# node_modules folder in an ASP.NET Core MVC project

Tags: node.js, git, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've recently upgraded my `netcoreapp1.0` to `netcoreapp1.1`. This left me wit ha few surprises and error that needed to be fixed. On top of that, I recently got a new PC, which forced me to go through even more things.

First up I had to install NodeJS again, and from the node package manager, install bower. After installing both NodeJS and bower, and several hours after working on my project, I realized, as I had to commit the changes to remote source control, that a `node_modules` folder had appeared (*though hidden*) in my project. Git of course wants to commit this folder, but I'd rather not since it contains loads of subfolders and other items.

[image: Hidden node_modules folder]

[image: Git changes for commit]

I was wondering what to do with this folder. I believe it shouldn't be there? And I'm not sure why it is. Shouldn't it be global or something, specific from PC to PC? Or should I just add it to my `.gitignore` file?

Quick info: It wasn't there prior to the upgraded project, meaning that I couldn't see any `node_modules` folder in `netcoreapp1.0` and there's no folder in my source control?

Comment: The node modules folder should have been there before if you have used it you can simply ignore it by adding node_modules to gitignore file like you say. Maybe the folder was in wwwroot before?

Comment: I see you installed Bower locally that's why the node_modules folder appeared. You can also install it globally.

Comment: @JoelHarkes so it's simply because it's installed locally and not globally?

Comment: @JoelHarkes If you would create an answer, I'd gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This node_modules folder wasn't there before because before it was installed globally:

```
npm install -g bower
```

the advantages of globally installing bower is that you can use the `bower` command through the command-line directly.

now apparently bower was installed locally, with the following command:

```
npm install bower
```

Now it was locally installed in the `node_modules` folder, meaning this folder appeared.

You don't need to check this folder into get and you can simple add the following rule in your .gitignore file:

```
node_modules
```

But 1 thing to remember! when you build your application with teamcity or some other CI build tool you will now need to install npm packages (just run `npm install` in the folder) before you publish your application, otherwise these javascript files will be missing.